# What's the easiest way to test a .NET SAML client?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, shibboleth

I will soon need to add SSO to an ASP.NET app using SAML.  The client will not provide access to their Shibboleth identity provider for testing, so I'll need to verify that SSO works myself.

What would be the easiest method to use/setup a SAML identity provider for testing?  I'm not keen on having to setup an infrastructure myself if I don't have to.

I'm planning on using a SAML component from http://www.componentspace.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your suggestions look quite helpful.

For others who may find this page, the ComponentSpace SAML 2.0 component comes with an Identity Provider that appears to mimic Shibboleth.  This appears to be the easiest way to test adding SSO to your own application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a SaaS Provider - Check out "Getting Ping Certified"

http://www.pingidentity.com/partners/becomeapartner.cfm